# When to use ngrx/effect in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-services, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an anuglar2 project that communicates with an api. Recently, I decided to integrate ngrx/store to maintain the state of the components, and follow the dump-smart component architecture. But then while moving on, I read about ngrx/effect which can be used upon the api requests.

And here my question comes, why should I use the ngrx/effect library, over just calling the corresponding function in my service from my container component to perform the api request and on success dispatch action to save the returned values in my store.

Answer (score 21):

If your case stays that simple, then you won't need an `effect` for it. Besides, the `effect` itself will do not much more than calling your service-method.

**In short**: If you project is very small and without many features, it will just cause you to write more code.

If you project is large, it will help you structure your data-flows and project-components.

---

#### When to use an effect:

When you want to trigger an action based on another action(in spoken english you would call this a *side-`effect`*) or when you want to add a generic error-handling or maybe a logging.

The way an `effect` works: The `effect` listens for any defined action(s) (e.g. *LoadDataAction*), then does some processing and returns any action(s) that are then processed by the store and distributed to a reducer or some other `effect`.

Example:

1. *LoadDataAction* is dispatched
2. an `effect`(*loadData$*) is triggered
3. the *loadData$*-`effect` calls the data-service
4. loading the data fails
5. the *loadData$*-`effect` return a *LoadDataFailureAction*

ngrx processes the action...

10. the *LoadDataFailureAction* might be picked up by:

    - a logger-effect(e.g. sends message to a server)
    - by an ui-notification-effect(e.g. displays message to user)
    - and/or by a reducer(e.g. persists the error-count or deletes something from the state)

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, you should to use ngrx/effects anytime you want to perform some asynchronous operation.

In a post on the subject, Jim Lynch says

> "You can almost think of your Effects as special kinds of reducer
>   functions that are meant to be a place for you to put your async calls
>   in such a way that the returned data can then be easily inserted into
>   the store’s internal state for the application."

link to article: https://medium.com/@flashMasterJim/the-basics-of-ngrx-effects-effect-and-async-middleware-for-ngrx-store-in-angular-2-f25587493329

Answer (score 0):

I honestly believe that the majority of apps that are using ngrx shouldn't be. Stores solve problems that most forms based applications don't encounter.

Have a look at a library I am working on that gives the push based data flow benefits of a store but makes it incredible simple to setup and reason about without any of the ridiculous amount of boilerplate involved with ngrx.

https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-rxcache

It is based on RxJs Behaviour Subjects and gives you all the benefits of push based data flow and still allows you to use the dumb-smart component architecture.

I have redone the official ngrx demo application in it here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-tsrf1f

If you compare it to the official ngrx demo app at

https://stackblitz.com/github/ngrx/platform/tree/61cbfe537f9df8cef3dd4a6ee0b8f483e49653f4

You will see how much simpler it is to setup and work with.