# Angular4 + Redux: who should dispatch action?

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx

In an Angular 4 app using Redux (with ngrx-store), I have the following:

a smart component that calls a service

```
this.contentService.update(this.content).subscribe( data => {
  //output some success message
});
```

a service that calls an API and then dispatch an action

```
update(content: Content) {
  return this.http.put(`http://someendpoint/contents.json`, { content })
  .map( (updated_content: Content) => {
    this.store.dispatch( { type: 'SOME_KEY', payload: updated_content }  );
    return updated_content;
  });
}
```

this approach is working really well, no problem. But I don't know if this is the right way: would it be better to let the component handle the response of the API an dispatch the action to the store? Should I separate this? What are the pros and cons? I can't find a good article about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd like to separate any logic from a data-/rest-service.

Basically you have many, many ways of handling this - in a big application I'd not even call the service directly from within the component, but only through an `@Effect` via a dispatched action.

But **there is no "one true" way**, it all depends on the architecture/style that you define - just make sure you keep it consistent and don't introduce a new way with every component/service.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I think I will follow this approach to separate the logic from my service, maybe using Effects (the app started very 'small' so I didn't think I will have much benefits using it, but now it's growing and maybe it's time to use them). :-)

Comment: I agree, Effects are the place to call services.

Comment: As I said: there is _no generic true solution_ - Refactoring always involves risk and most often requires quite a bit of effort - if you are the only developer working on the application and if it's below 50 files I'd personally don't invest the time and keep it as it is - with `@Effects` you might find other things that may annoy you, it will __not__ be magically better ;-)  (though it might be cleaner, it will for sure be more work)

Comment: @olsn using Effects, when I dispatch some action, I can call my service. Then, inside it's subscribce() method, can I dispatch another action that my reducers will manage (and then change the state from my store)? Is this a good approach?

Comment: Close, but not entirely, have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113814/when-to-use-ngrx-effect-in-angular2/44114123#44114123  (you can replace the "Failure" in the example with "Success" - the data-flow is the same)

Comment: @olsn thanks! Great link, I have understood this. BTW, do you have any tip about how to know when an Effect occurs? Let's explain: I can have an effect that calls my API to change some data. My component (frontend) shows a spinner when I dispatch the action to the Effect. But I don't know how to deal with this, to hide the spinner. Should I store some flag in my store?

Comment: Yes, the UI is bascially the representation of the store - so, if you want a spinner to show, the preferred solution is to set a  flag in the store - I usually use a counter: it goes +1 for every started request and -1 for every ended(cancel, failed, succeeded) request, if the counter is > 0  => show a global spinner - that way you don't need a separate flag for each request - but if you still want a separate flag, that should be no problem as well

Comment: Alternatively you can also listen for actions in your component and have the service dispatch an action like "showContentSpinner" and "hideContentSpinner" -> that way you don't need to keep a state for the spinner (again... there is no right or wrong - just make sure that the solution fits your project and preferences)